# Why is Java 'Comparable' better than just using a compareTo method?

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

1. I see that `Comparable` interface allowed implementation of just the `compareTo` method. So why do we even need this interface? Why can't we simply define and declare the method in any class we want, without having to implement the `Comparable` interface?
2. I understand that this is correct: `SortedSet<String> exampleSet = new TreeSet<String>();` <-- `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet` interface. So if I have a class called "`Date`" that implements `Comparable`, is this correct: `Comparable<Date> example = new Date<Date>();`. If yes, what exactly do I get? I mean what kind of object do I get? What properties does it have? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't we simply define and declare the method in any class we want, without having to implement the Comparable interface?

How would you expect a sorting method to work in that case?

It's really handy to be able to sort any collection where the elements are all comparable with each other - and an interface is the way to express that.

> is this correct: `Comparable<Date> example = new Date<Date>();`

No, not unless `Date` itself were generic. You *could* write:

```
Comparable<Date> example = new Date();
```

... but it would be odd to do so. Normally `Comparable` is used by code which wants to compare *existing* objects - so it would fetch values from a collection and compare them with each other, for example.

Comment: `How would you expect a sorting method to work in that case?` = By writing just the `compareTo` method? I mean we still need to write the method for any class that implements the `Comparable` interface, right? So for the `Date` class, say, I want to compare 2 dates (DD/MM/YYYY), I would have to write a `compareTo` method that actually does all the comparing work. So if I don't implement `Comparable` in this class, how is my program different?

Comment: @user2027425: Jon's point is that if you want some _outside_ code to be able to help provide utilities like e.g. sorting, it has to know how to hook into your code and compare different elements.  Implementing `Comparable` is primarily so that you can use other code, or libraries built into Java, that know how to do useful and helpful things with comparable elements.

Comment: @user2027425: The difference is that in your case, you'd need to write the same sorting code over and over again: once for `Date`, once for `Foo`, once for `Bar` the `compareTo` method in each case, because there'd be nothing to say, "Hey - these types are all the same in the only way I care about, namely how one value compares to another." That's the *only* thing that sorting cares about, so why would you want to write the code to do the sorting in a way which cared which type you used?

Comment: But if I didn't implement `Comparable`, I would still be required to write the `compareTo` for `Date`, `Foo` and `Bar`. I'm sorry, I know you are trying to explain, but I really do not understand - it's my fault.

Comment: @user2027425: Yes, you still have to write `compareTo` in each case - that's unavoidable - but you can write the code that *calls* it just once, because it doesn't need to care what it's comparing, so long as it can compare things.

Comment: Ahh.. I think it's starting to make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we simply define and declare the method in any class we
>   want, without having to implement the Comparable interface?

Some `Collections` like `TreeMap`, need to compare two objects, even for a simple `add()` operation. Such a tree needs that to internally put "smaller" object in the left tree, and bigger ín the right subtree (a bit simplified).
Because such a generic Collection (like TreeMap), is designed to work for all Objects, the Object, then must know how to perfrom a compareTo().

Other Collections like HashMaps do not need that the Objects implement Comparable (They use `hashcode`())